# Java client for MS Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Do we have any client library which we can use directly in a java project to access data through microsoft graph api's. I don't want to write my one http request handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a Java library today and are aware of customer requests for one.  I encourage you to upvote this [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/5952065-office-365-sdk-for-java) request for a Java library so we can see how much interest there is.

For Android mobile applications, we have an Android client library but that won't work for Java server apps.

Comment: Thanks for the response